# Flash Playback and HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, flash, video

I'm looking for a solution to provide streaming video to a variety of clients. I have iPhone clients as well as Flash-based clients.  I'd like to not have to provide two separate mechanisms for delivering streaming content.  Apple has decreed that [HTTP Live Streaming](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-05) is *the* way to provide streaming video to the iPhone (though does carve out an exception for small progressive downloads).

My question: Are there examples of Flash implementations consuming HTTP Live Streaming content?  What challenges might be faced if I were to try and implement such a player? Are there other technologies I should consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Not yet.  Maybe never.  But...

What you could do is stream from a [Wowza Media Server](http://wowzamedia.com), which will allow you to publish one stream that can be consumed by various clients, including both Apple client devices and Flash browser clients.